# JBoss 7 Request header is too large

Tags: jsp, jboss

I have a JBoss Application Server 7 is being used.
However, the error appeared.
0:25:18,504 DEBUG [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor] (http-jboss.ap.com-192.168.0.32-80-7) Error parsing HTTP request header: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request header is too large

How can this be solved please?
In jboss7 a way to increase the size of the post for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the **maxPostSize** attribute.

This
http://programmaremobile.blogspot.com/2009/05/request-header-too-large-exception.html
lead me here
http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/config/http.html

Comment: Answer Thank you. But
I is version 7.1.0 FINAL
In admin condsole
Configuration-> Http Service-> Http Listener can not find the path.

Comment: You may be able to edit this properties file then restart the container. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org$nexus$content$repositories$releases@org.jboss.as$jboss-as-web@7.1.0.Beta1b@org$jboss$as$web$LocalDescriptions.properties?av=o#web.connector.max-post-size

Comment: I saw the url you sent I do not know what to do.
In the admin console do I need to add to the system properites?